# parallax background image is not display on iphone but it is display on android how can i fix this

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, parallax

i wanted to create a parallax, it display very well on android but when i open it on iphone or ios tablet the backgroun image dissapear. There is no problem on android or windows device. How can i fix this any idea and also when i click dropdown on android the dropdown menu works but on ios device it is not working. Here is domain. gokkar.com have a nice days thx

```
    .parallaxSet{
 background-attachment: fixed;/*background-size: 2261.76px 1178px;*/background-position: 50% -103.564px;
 -webkit-background-size: 100%; 
-moz-background-size: 100%; 
-o-background-size: 100%; 
background-size: 100%; 
}

<div class="parallax background section-height parallaxSet" style="background-image: url(assets/images/banner2.jpg);" data-diff="200">
                <div class="parallax-wrapper">
                    <div class="parallax-scroll">

                        <div class="lastline">
                            <h5>GÖKKAR KURUMSAL</h5>
                            <h6>‘‘Şirketimiz 22 Aralık 1995 tarihinde kurulmuştur. 5 Ocak 1996 tarih ve 3951 sayılı Ticaret Sicili Gazetesi’nde yayımlanarak tescil edilmiştir.’’</h6>
                            <a href="hakkimizda/">İncele</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

<style>
.parallax {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

  .parallax:after {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;

    border-width: 60px;
    margin-left: -60px;
    z-index: 250;
  }

  .parallax.overflow,
  .parallax.overflow .parallax-wrapper {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

  .parallax.background {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-position: 50% 50%\9 !important;
  }

  .parallax.section-height {
    height: 400px;
  }

  .parallax-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .parallax-scroll {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .lastline {
    width: 60%;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0;
  }

  .lastline > h5 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .lastline > h6 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }

  .lastline > a {
    width: 300px;
    height: 55px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 35px auto;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .lastline > a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
  }


</style>
```

Comment: looks okay for me, make sure that you have a clean cache on your phone. Delte your Cache and look again.

Comment: i did and also i tried it on many device have you check the link gokkar.com i have also have a problem with links , dropdown doesn't work on iphone like android

Answer (score 0):

You are changing your header from fixed to position: static on devices with max-width: 800px

change:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
   header {
      height: auto;
      position: static;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
      display: block;
}
```

To:

```
position: fixed;
```

You will also have to add some margin top so the background image doesn't sit under the header.

Comment: thx for that but i have a problem with parallax does it solve my problem?

Comment: The fix above makes the site work the same on windows desktop and iPhone 5s (emulated through chrome) Im not sure what you mean by the parallax? On desktop the header image just scrolls underneath the nav. Is that what you want?

Answer (score -1):

IOS deactivated the "`background-attachment:fixed`" feature to reduce the costs on mobile devices.

Your only option is to use `background-attachment:scroll`. That dosen't the same effect as you wanted but you could do a workaround with some JavaScript as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QN9cH/1/)

**The better way:**
Use a Media Query and show a Single image with a fixed position.

Comment: thanks for the answer but shame that JS solution doesnt work :( The image keeps moving